# Twisted: Ignore Prefetch Requests from Safari Search Bar

Tags: python, http, safari, twisted

I have a twisted server that creates and serves large files in response to GET requests. I am doing this by creating a `twisted.protocols.basic.FileSender` inside the `render_GET` method of a `twisted.web.resource.Resource` (I don't know if this is the best way, but it works).

The issue I'm having is that I notice that as I type URLs in the Safari search bar, the server gets a new request each time I type a character. I understand why Safari does this, but it is suboptimal for my server to respond to these requests. Safari rightly asks the server to stop producing the file (I see 'Consumer asked us to stop producing' in the log), but constructing the files wastes resources on the server if the client didn't want them in the first place (especially since a lot can come as the user types).

I haven't noticed anything in the request headers that would distinguish these (prefetch?) requests. Might there be some way that I can detect and ignore them?

---

Edit: the following is what twisted returns for getAllHeaders()

```
{b'connection': b'keep-alive',
 b'accept': b'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 b'host': b'localhost:4002',
 b'accept-language': b'en-us',
 b'user-agent': b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38',
 b'upgrade-insecure-requests': b'1',
 b'accept-encoding': b'gzip, deflate'
}
```

Comment: It doesn't send a `"X-Purpose: prefetch" or "Purpose: prefetch"` header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ#As_a_server_admin.2C_can_I_distinguish_prefetch_requests_from_normal_requests.3F

Comment: No, it doesn't, although I expected to see that (I'm guessing Safari doesn't consider these requests prefetches). I edited my question to show the headers that twisted reports.